# ¿Cuándo es obligatorio el uso de punto y coma?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

En el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XAD3nkRJmD6NjdyDQ0), se especifican cuatro usos del punto y coma:

> 1. Para separar los elementos de una enumeración cuando se trata de expresiones complejas que incluyen comas.
> 2. Para separar oraciones sintácticamente independientes entre las que existe una estrecha relación semántica.
> 3. Se escribe punto y coma delante de conectores de sentido adversativo, concesivo o consecutivo, como *pero*, *mas*, *aunque*, *sin embargo*, *por tanto*, *por consiguiente*, etc., cuando las oraciones que encabezan tienen cierta longitud.
> 4. Se pone punto y coma detrás de cada uno de los elementos de una lista o relación cuando se escriben en líneas independientes y se inician con minúscula, salvo detrás del último, que se cierra con punto.

Sin embargo, también dejan claro que el punto y coma es un signo de uso subjetivo y poco frecuente, y aclaran que en numerosas ocasiones es posible sustituirlo por otro, pero al mismo tiempo dicen que no es prescindible (negritas mías):

> El punto y coma es, de todos los signos de puntuación, el que presenta un **mayor grado de subjetividad** en su empleo, pues, en muchos casos, **es posible** optar, en su lugar, por otro signo de puntuación, como el punto y seguido, los dos puntos o la coma; pero **esto no significa que el punto y coma sea un signo prescindible**.
>
> [...]
>
> En **la mayor parte** de estos casos, se podría utilizar el punto y seguido. La elección de uno u otro signo **depende** de la vinculación semántica que **quien escribe** considera que existe entre los enunciados. Si el vínculo se estima débil, se prefiere usar el punto y seguido; si se juzga más sólido, es conveniente optar por el punto y coma.

Entonces, ante esta ambigüedad, ¿en alguno de los cuatro casos anteriormente expuestos debe considerarse obligatorio su uso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He revisado la *Ortografía 2010* (que es cinco años posterior al DPD, y más completa). En ningún momento se especifica que [el punto y coma](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KGzINbiHyEasazBQ) deba ser obligatorio: tan solo da pautas para su correcto uso y menciona casos en los que se puede (que no debe) usar.

El texto de la Ortografía cita los siguientes ejemplos en el epígrafe 3.4.3.1:

> *Era el jardín de tilos, con sus mecedoras de lona y sus mesas de mimbre; los salones espaciosos con muebles firmados y tapices del XVI; la biblioteca salpicada de incunables; la sala de estar con sus cuadros antiguos, sus porcelanas del Retiro y sus jarros de La Granja; los vestíbulos, con sus estatuas romanas, sus alfombras persas; el comedor con su cristalería francesa, sus platos ingleses, y su cubertería jeroglífico...*
>
> Mercedes Salisachs, "La gangrena", 1975 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Si le cuento lo de la pesadilla en la terraza, no me creerá; si me cree, me tomará por loco; si no le cuento, por estúpido.*
>
> Vlady Kociancich, "La octava maravilla", 1982 (Argentina).

Partiendo de estos textos, la *Ortografía 2010* dice:

> No se trata, sin embargo, de un signo prescindible; al contrario, resulta muy valioso en dos sentidos:
>
> a) Como jerarquizador de la información, ya que aclara las relaciones de los elementos que constituyen el texto. Así, en el ejemplo mencionado de Mercedes Salisachs, que reproduce una compleja enumeración, la distribución de los signos de punto y coma y de coma facilita la rápida percepción de las relaciones sintácticas, de manera que, sin esfuerzo, el que lee identifica los elementos coordinados en un nivel superior: *el jardín de tilos, los salones espaciosos, la biblioteca, la sala de estar, los vestíbulos y el comedor*, elementos que no se confunden con otros pertenecientes a enumeraciones de nivel inferior, como *muebles firmados* y *tapices del XVI* o como *sus cuadros antiguos, sus porcelanas del Retiro y sus jarros de La Granja*. [...]
>
> b) Como indicador de la vinculación semántica que quien escribe establece entre las unidades lingüísticas, es decir, del grado de dependencia y relevancia que desea imprimir a cada una de ellas. En este sentido, es un signo intermedio entre la coma y el punto: establece mayor disociación entre las unidades que la coma —y, por tanto, realza más cada una de ellas— y menor que la indicada por el punto. Así, en el ejemplo mencionado de Vlady Kociancich, la elección del punto y coma frente al punto favorece la concatenación de las ideas expresadas en las tres construcciones condicionales, que aparecen a ojos del lector como una única secuencia de información.

Una vez soltada esta parrafada, recalcar que no, que el punto y coma siempre se puede intercambiar por otro signo, aunque existen aspectos sutiles como los mencionados que hacen útil el punto y coma en determinadas situaciones.